# Têm como melhorar o meu código?

Tags: c, for, revisão-de-código

Olá sou Vitor e sou novo na programação e no Stack Overflow e gostaria de umas dicas de como deixar meu codigo mais limpo.->Código para ler 50 números inteiros entre 0 e 9 e contar quantas vezes cada numero foi digitado.

Obs: Ignorem os comentários do código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

//Faça um programa que lê 50 valores inteiros entre 0 e 9 e 
//conte quantas vezes cada numero foi digitado.//

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int contador = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int vetor[10];

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){

        vetor[i] = 0;

    }

    printf("Leitura do vetor com 50 números entre 0 e 9\n");

    for(i=0; i <= 10; i++){/*For para limitar numeros entre 0 e 9*/
        if(contador < 50){/*If para percorrer o máximo de vezes pelo laço obedecendo o for de que os numeros seja de 0 á 9*/

            printf("Digite um numero de 0 a 9: ");
            scanf("%d", &i);

            contador++;
            vetor[i]++;
        }
   }


        printf("\nImpressão/n");

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            printf("\nNúmero %d : %d vezes\n",i,vetor[i]);

        }

        system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow.

Supondo que você realmente é um iniciante em programação, seu código está relativamente bom. Não sei em que ponto você está e nem por qual motivo entrou na programação (escola técnica ou faculdade, por exemplo), mas tem algumas formas de melhorar o código em questão de estética.

Também sou um estudante de programação e confesso que não tenho conhecimentos suficientes em desempenho de algoritimos, mas vou ajudar da forma que posso.

Primeiramente, é fundamental o uso de funções, para dividir melhor o problema em pequenas partes. Se você estiver bem no inicio, não precisa se preocupar tanto, mas é bom já ir se acostumando com as funções.

Para mim, sua lógica está boa, bastando melhorar um pouco a estetica. Vou deixar um exemplo aqui abaixo para você ver como é a estrutura do mesmo código feito com funções.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readNumbers(int vet[]){
    int cont, num;
    for(cont=0;cont<5;cont++){
        printf("Digite um numero de 0 a 9: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        vet[num]++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printTimes(int vet[]){
    int cont;
    for(cont=0;cont<10;cont++)
        printf("O numero %d foi digitado %d vezes.\n", cont, vet[cont]);
}

int main(){
    int typedTimes[10]={0};
    readNumbers(typedTimes);
    printTimes(typedTimes);
}
```

Lembrando novamente que não sou especialista em desempenho, mas não precisa se preocupar com isso agora.

Algumas mudanças que fiz:

1. Transferi as tarefas de ler e printar os números para funções
2. Retirei a biblioteca "math", pois não vi utilidade para seu código
3. Retirei os argumentos da main(), pois como iniciante, é bom você saber o que é e para que serve, mas não precisa utilizar agora.
4. Na hora de criar o vetor, eliminei o for que você fez para preencher o vetor com "0", fazendo tudo isso na declaração apenas atribuindo o "0" entre os { }.

Caso a ideia de funções seja muito nova para você, recomendo que você treine um pouco mais sem elas. Depois é só procurar algum conteúdo no youtube sobre a lógica das funções.

Recomendo para treinar a lógica o site do UriOnlineJudge, lá você encontra diversos problemas e dá para dar uma brincada.

Bons estudos!